# jQuery get clicked div only and not children

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've mocked my head around this issue more than once, I have no idea I have tried basically everything I could find on Google and stack overflow, nothing worked.

What happens is sometimes I get the `span` and other times the `div` - why?

```js
$(".bind-key").on("click", (ev) => {
  console.log(ev.target)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bkey-1" class="bind-key cursor-pointer bg-gray-700 text-gray-400 w-max px-2 p-1 rounded-md">
  <span>KEY</span>
</div>
```

Output:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwXVK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `target` will be the element which raised the event. Due to event bubbling this may be, in your example, the `span` if you clicked the word 'KEY' directly, or the `div` if you clicked the whitespace to the right.

To change this behaviour use the `currentTarget` property. This will always refer to the element the event was bound to, no matter which child element caused the event to bubble up the DOM. Try this:

```js
$(".bind-key").on("click", e => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget); // this will always be the .bind-key element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bkey-1" class="bind-key cursor-pointer bg-gray-700 text-gray-400 w-max px-2 p-1 rounded-md">
  <span>KEY</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Although to further elaborate this thread, any way I can get that to work with jQuery's functions? For example I'd like to get the currentTarget and use jQuery's .text() function on it's child, any way?

Comment: Sure `$(e.currentTarget).children().first().text()` would work here, or if you know you want to find the `span` specifically use `.children('span').text()` or `find('span').text()`